# How to access JSON type object property stored inside data object in Vue's template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, templates

I have a data object in a Vue.js app

```js
data() {
  return {
    group1: {
      id:   'qd4TTgajyDexFAZ5RKFP',
      owners: {
        john:  {age: 32, gender: 'man'},
        mary: {age: 34, gender: 'woman'},
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get Mary's age inside Vue's template like this...

I can get to `owners` like this...

```html
<p>{{group1.owners}}</p>
```

but if I try to drill further like this...

```html
<p>{{group1.owners.mary.age}}</p>
```

...I get an error message saying it can't get to `mary` of undefined .

`"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"`

Anyone out there who can help?

Comment: You probably want "qd4TTgajyDexFAZ5RKFP"  to be a string, same goes for man and woman. Because without any quotes it's looking for a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that rather

```html
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        group1: {
          id: 'qd4TTgajyDexFAZ5RKFP',
          owners: {
            john: {
              age: 32,
              gender: 'man'
            },
            mary: {
              age: 34,
              gender: 'woman'
            },
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <pre>result: {{ group1.owners.mary.age }}</pre>
</template>
```

Here is a [working example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9UclqwzAQ/ZVBl7SQyHS7GBMIlFx6KSWnoosaTxybaOlIzoLxv3fsOEtTKAhpRnrzRu9NI2bey22NIhVZWFLp41RZ3HtHEXJc6XoToVEWINdR390fYwDCWJM9ZQAFudo/pJcLgDJPYfSdPy8Wha4Or7ifzz5fPt7m7yMYX1BuZ5HCr0KAyq1tCtDoAlN4ehxDgTZHYj6j7ai9Kgcwmg5cfoQ+X0F37hbcnsIh6A/eeGXJWTwnEY3f6IicAWSecEoY2Anu0wxS5fHjsmsvuTm0bZZ0yI7rXC/GojSdlxOjvayCs+xzL1UND0GJs3gleBBdrsQ6Rh/SJAmrZTedKkhHRcKRpNrG0qDEYCZf5HYBiYmVGHT2HAlfbpEm1HuB9B/nDfQP78kj0f4AN4ezUA==).